# What determines the size of an excel file?

Tags: excel, filesize

I work with Excel a lot and I am sometimes surprised why some files can only be a few kB, while others are tens of MB. It doesn't necessarily seem consistent with how much data is in the sheets; some have macros, some don't. I was therefore wondering whether something else, such as (conditional) formatting has an impact on file size. I guess that a large sheet filled with the same long formula might be a culprit too?

*I appreciate this question is quite general and I'm surprised that my research 
hasn't found it asked before, hence here it is.*

Comment: If it is a `.xlsx` file it is entirely due to how string compression working with repeating paterns

Comment: Welcome to [so].  Actually, this question does not belongs here, which is not programming-related.  And you may "extract" the excel file and check what in those XML.

Comment: @Prisoner, I'd add that you can only view them as XML if the file it's not saved as a `.xlsb` (which extracts binary files). Also some items will not show up when extracted, which can be large -- like the Data Model.

Comment: Also OP - a better search is probably "how to *reduce* file size" -- it's what everyone really wants to know